# How to Bind Selected Rows From Grid View to Another Grid View

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, data-binding, datatable

I would to add the selected rows from gridview into another gridview. Could someone help me on this? When I try to bind gridview to another gridview, another gridview doesn't appear.

The aspx file I posted below is about how I created the gridview. The gridview1 will get its gridview contents from the database table. While the cs file is about how I am going to bind selected rows from gridview1 into gridview2. The problem now is when I try to bind the rows over, the gridview2 didn't appear, only gridview1 appeared.

This is my codes:

**ASPX file:**

```
<h3 class="h3">Grid View1</h3>
<div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: auto">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
                  runat="server"
                  AllowSorting="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  Width="100%"
                  CellPadding="6"
                  ForeColor="#333333"
                  GridLines="Horizontal"
                  BorderColor="Black"
                  BorderStyle="Solid"
                  BorderWidth="2px"
                  EmptyDataText="Record Not Found"
                  OnRowDataBound="GridView1_OnRowDataBound">
        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE"
                            HeaderText="DATE"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE"
                            HeaderText="CODE"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PROFILE_NAME"
                            HeaderText="PROFILE_NAME"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION"
                            HeaderText="DESCRIPTION"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS"
                            HeaderText="STATUS"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USER"
                            HeaderText="USER"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB_USER"
                            HeaderText="SUB_USER"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SCORE"
                            HeaderText="SCORE"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ROLE"
                            HeaderText="ROLE"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANTITY"
                            HeaderText="QUANTITY"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM"
                            HeaderText="ITEM"></asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE"
                            HeaderText="PRICE"></asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
        <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
        <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1"
                     Font-Bold="False"
                     ForeColor="Black" />
        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1"
                     Font-Bold="False"
                     ForeColor="Black"
                     BorderStyle="Solid"
                     BorderWidth="2px" />
        <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF"
                    ForeColor="White"
                    HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
        <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1"
                          Font-Bold="False"
                          ForeColor="#333333" />
        <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
        <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
        <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
    </asp:GridView>
    <h3 class="h3">Grid View2</h3>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: auto">
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2"
                      runat="server"
                      AllowSorting="True"
                      AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                      Width="100%"
                      CellPadding="6"
                      ForeColor="#333333"
                      GridLines="Horizontal"
                      BorderColor="Black"
                      BorderStyle="Solid"
                      BorderWidth="2px"
                      EmptyDataText="Record Not Found"
                      OnRowDataBound="GridView2_OnRowDataBound">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DATE"
                                HeaderText="DATE"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CODE"
                                HeaderText="CODE"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PROFILE_NAME"
                                HeaderText="PROFILE_NAME"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="DESCRIPTION"
                                HeaderText="DESCRIPTION"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="STATUS"
                                HeaderText="STATUS"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="USER"
                                HeaderText="USER"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SUB_USER"
                                HeaderText="SUB_USER"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SCORE"
                                HeaderText="SCORE"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ROLE"
                                HeaderText="ROLE"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="QUANTITY"
                                HeaderText="QUANTITY"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="ITEM"
                                HeaderText="ITEM"></asp:BoundField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="PRICE"
                                HeaderText="PRICE"></asp:BoundField>
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1"
                         Font-Bold="False"
                         ForeColor="Black" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1"
                         Font-Bold="False"
                         ForeColor="Black"
                         BorderStyle="Solid"
                         BorderWidth="2px" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF"
                        ForeColor="White"
                        HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1"
                              Font-Bold="False"
                              ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>
```

**CS file:**

```
protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs     e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if (Convert.ToString(DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, “USER”)) == “ALAN TAN”)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(“DATE”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“CODE”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“PROFILE_NAME”);

            dt.Columns.Add(“DESCRIPTION”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“STATUS”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“USER”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“SUB_USER”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“SCORE”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“ROLE”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“QUANTITY”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“ITEM”);
            dt.Columns.Add(“PRICE”);
            DataRow dataRow;
            dataRow = dt.NewRow();
            int i2 = 1;
            for(int i=0; i<dataRow.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                dataRow[i] = GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[i2].Text;
                i2++;
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dataRow);
            GridView2.DataSource = dt;
            GridView2.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I Really didn't understand messy code done by you (Too many things are missing in your question). Refer below links that will explain you will example.

- http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Transfer-Selected-Rows-from-one-GridView-to-Another-in-Asp.net.aspx
- http://www.ittutorials.in/source/aspDotnet/scf13/move-gridview-rows-from-one-gridview-to-another.aspx

Updates:

`dt.Rows.Add()` must be inside of for loop so everytime it will get add new row.

try to update following code in cs file

```
for(int i=0; i<dataRow.Table.Columns.Count; i++)
{ 
   dt.Rows.Add(GridView1.SelectedRow.Cells[i2].Text);
   i2++;
}
GridView2.DataSource = dt;
GridView2.DataBind();
```

Comment: hi Bhavik Patel, thanks for the links provided. I have read through the links u sent. But I would like to check if there's a value existed in a column of a gridview, then only add those rows that have the value existed in that column into datatable. The links you provided is to check what user has selected from checkbox in gridview then add those rows into the datatable. It's not what I am searching for.

Comment: The aspx file I posted is about how I created the gridview. The gridview1 will get its gridview contents from the database table. While the cs file is about how I am going to bind selected rows from gridview1 into gridview2. The problem now is when I try to bind the rows over, the gridview2 didn't appear, only gridview1 appeared.